# Combining the following VBA code:

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to safely combine all this code. The is issue is repeated BeforeClose names that have to be avoided. I was a little confused how to get around this.

//full screen

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Application.CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.DisplayFullScreen = False
Application.CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = True
End Sub
```

//formula bar

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
End Sub
```

//headings

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.DisplayHeadings = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.DisplayHeadings = False
End Sub
```

//drag and drop

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    chgflag = "Y"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   If chgflag <> "Y" Then
     MsgBox ("You are Closing this before Generating Your Target Docs")
   End If
   Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub
```

Many Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Is `chgflag` a public variable you have declared somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

The `Workbook_Open` or `Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` is the trigger to execute the commands you desire at those given times. So, put all the commands between the `Private Sub` and `End Sub` statements. For instance;

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
  Application.CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = False
  Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
  Application.DisplayHeadings = False
  Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub
```

Do the same for the `BeforeClose` event.

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    chgflag = "Y"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   If chgflag <> "Y" Then
     MsgBox ("You are Closing this before Generating Your Target Docs")
   End If
   Application.CellDragAndDrop = True

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
  Application.CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = False
  Application.DisplayHeadings = False
  Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub